# DC-DC buck output voltage

Tags: battery-charging, buck, lipo, step-down, lithium-polymer

I am designing a DC-DC step-down converter (asynchronous) and I would like to achieve a Li-Po charging with it (18 - 22 V input voltage). My goal is the CC/CV charging but to do this, I need constant voltage (4.2 V) on the output. I have simulated the circuit in MATLAB simulink (with battery model) but I can only measure the battery voltage.
I am monitoring the input current/voltage and the output current/voltage too.
I am so confused with this now, I have read many topics, articles.
Can I achieve CC/CV with asynchronous buck converter?

**EDIT:**

I have found a CC/CV design for buck:
https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/powerhouse/archive/2017/11/24/how-to-design-a-simple-constant-current-constant-voltage-buck-converter

Can I achieve it with asynchronous buck too?

**EDIT2:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faLLCD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Of course! Why would you not? The CC/CV is on a macroscopic scale compared to whether the rectification is synchronous or not.

Comment: Thank you!
For example if the battery's voltage at 3.8 V, the output of the buck is 3.8 V too?
So if I adjust the duty cycle the current changes only (I experienced this while simulating)?

Comment: That's once again a macroscopic effect you are seeing. Please show how you have or are planning to implement your CC/CV control and feedback. In general, for battery chargers you will see the difference apart form efficiency and complexity when it comes to reverse battery voltage protection and operation very close to zero volt.

Comment: I have edited my question.
This is my current "raw" schematic.

Comment: Why two current measurements? Apart from that, you should have everything you need and "just" need to implement your CC/CV regulation and loop compensation in your uC.

Comment: This is a solar charger system. I have to know the input current and voltage to know the power of the PV panel and I have to monitor the output current not to exceed a limit.
Is the output correct with the Zener or should I use another solution (like LDO)?

Comment: I see. You could omit one current measurement and compute that one if you want to save a few bucks. Zener will only clamp output voltage, not current. You don’t trust your uC to do this for you, or do you “just” need load dump?

Comment: I just want to keep the output is at 4.2 V if the charging is at CV state. I was thinking about one current measurement method but I don't know how accurately could I define the current.

Comment: You could technically cheat on both current and voltage on the input and do MPPT anyway but it should be easier to implement with at least input voltage measurement. Measure your efficiency or model an equivalent resistance and you’ve got Uin*Iin=n*Uout*Iout or Uin*Iin=Iout(1-D*Rdson)*Vout.